# Base64 string in SSIS

Tags: ssis, base64

I have a database table with a field "FileName" and a second field which is a base64 string (nvarchar(MAX)). It's an archive from my financial system. I want to convert this string back into a file using an Byte[] in a SSIS script task but i can't get the string value out of this object variable.

First I get the value from the SQL database in a SSIS variable (Base64Data). This variable is of type Object since the SQL type is nvarchar(MAX). I use sql statement: *SELECT Base64Data FROM SubjectConnector WHERE FileName= '16-VMA-37041.pdf'* which returns only one row. I then connect the Base64Data to a variable [User::Base64Data] in the Result Set window of the Execute SQL Task Editor. No problems here (at least so it seems).

But when I check the value of this object variable with:
*MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::Base64Data"].Value.ToString());*
it states:
*System._ComObject*

What it's going on? Is the result from the SQL query empty? How can I check this or what else is wrong?

[Here's my SQL data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUfw.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Variable type Object is in fact ADO recordset, so you cannot get it directly with `Dts.Variables...` statement. I extracted NVARCHAR(MAX) value with *FOR EACH* enumerator for ADO.NET recordset, and fetched value from the first column into text variable.

Comment: Yep, that's it. As long as the object variable is a full result set and not single row!

Thanx Ferdipux!